# Get disk usage as a shell variable

Tags: shell, disk-usage

The goal is to trigger an automatic alert when disk usage goes above a given threshold. So far I have only found the command `df -hP /disk/path` that returns disk usage. However, it returns lots of other information as well, as in the image below.

[image: Screenshot of df command and result]

I am looking for the most convenient way to retrieve the `Use%` statistic. Either through Regex or another Linux command.

It is different from existing question in that it only deals with extracting the right value from the `df` command while the other questions deal with this part, plus sending the alert as well. The top answer given to this question which I accepted is the most elegant way I have seen to extract the right value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this :

```
df -hP /disk/path | awk '{print $5}' |tail -1|sed 's/%$//g'
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Seems like I should really learn about awk and sed if I were to work with Linux more.

Comment: @KarolisRamanauskas If helped upvote it and mark it as answered.